# Using Accelometer in unity,to move a gameobject with in the scene

Tags: accelerometer, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am placing 2 gameobjects at the left down corner and right upper of the screen. So I am using 2 gameobjects to form a border. And using boundaries class to create a bound such that it will stop the pivot point of my gameobject and I will move it inside bound using accelometer (It means I have 2 borders, outer border and inner border, I am drawing inner border using bounds with width and height calculating from formula I derived).

This is the code

```
void Start () 
{
 valueOfHeight = (Screen.height * 110 )/ 320;
 valueOfWidth = (Screen.width * 110 )/ 480;

 Boundaries = new Bounds (new Vector3(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2,0f),new Vector3(Screen.width - valueOfWidth,Screen.height - valueOfHeight,0f));

 }

 void Update () 
 {
   if(gameObject.transform.position.x > Cornerpoints [1].transform.position.x &&
    gameObject.transform.position.x < Cornerpoints [3].transform.position.x&&
    gameObject.transform.position.y > Cornerpoints [1].transform.position.y&&
gameObject.transform.position.y < Cornerpoints [3].transform.position.y) 
   {
    Debug.Log("1");
    gameObject.transform.position =   Boundaries.ClosestPoint(gameObject.transform.position);

if (Boundaries.Contains (gameObject.transform.position)) 
{
   Debug.Log("2");
  direction = new Vector3 ((Input.acceleration.x), (Input.acceleration.y), 0);
}
```

But the problem here my gameobject is jerking on one side of the border (mostly left side).If the problem is occurs on all sides means,my code is wrong.But its only occuring only on left side of the border and i checked logs,(i kept logs 1 and 2),see when gameobejct comes to left side of the border,its 1 is only executing so that it is looking like jerking.But it is not happening on all sides.SO i want to know why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be better to include the code as a formatted text instead of and image of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,i am going to change it